# How to point URL to directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, htaccess

I need to point web url's like

```
http://example.com/subdir1
http://example.com/subdir2
```

to same directory

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/default/
```

on Linux hosting (Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2) - how to do that, please?
Maybe it can be solved using .httaccess? If not, is there any other option, please?

Comment: First, which one is your webroot directory. I'm assuming /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/ , right? 
If so, subdir1 and subdir2 are inside httpdocs, as well as the default directory. Redirects can be done either through the vhost config file, or throug htaccess. You can use regular expressions to follow some kind of rule when to redirect some directories, to the default directory.

Comment: Thank you for your analyze, actually subdir1 and subdir2 does not exists, they just need to point to directory /var/www/vhosts/...
Yes, .htaccess will be pefect - if you can give me some example, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the web root directory is under `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/`, 
and you need to redirect any sub-directory to the 'default' sub-directory, you would need an .htaccess rule like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir.*$ /default/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

You can test your htaccess rule on a site like this one: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ 
What that site is doing, is checking the Regular Expression you have provided on the first block of the the RewriteRule, and the matched results will get redirected to the path you want to.

Keep in mind that the above rule might not always work, depending on your apache configuration.

You can play with different regex expression by testing the expression on sites like https://regex101.com/

Also a good place to learn about regex is https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you for your work but this is not what I need. Your .htaccess forward subdir to default but what I need is to stay on subdir url and to read data and configuration from default. Do you have any example for that, please?

Comment: As far as I can tell, thats not possible with apache, but you can read more here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html
With the apache rewrite rules, you basically redirect a directory or URL to another to make it look cleaner for example, but not get the contents of another directory for different URLs.

Comment: This works fine in vhost.conf:

    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
         Alias /subdir "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/default" 
    </IfModule>

how to do that in htaccess, please?

Comment: Try RewriteRule ^subdir(.*)$ /default/$1 [R=301,NC,L] 
Alias won't work in .htaccess. But if it works on the apache config, I suggest you use that. Its way better than using htaccess.